# Writing/reading escape characters to/from files in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `.txt` file which contains lots of lines of data separated with the `|` character. Here's an example of a line - as you can see **it already contains escape sequences**. They're there because I don't know how else to preserve paragraphing and indentation in a .csv-esque system. Let's assume I'm stuck with this.

```
Example.|This is an example.\n\nLook at this paragraph.|Great.
```

I'm **not** having problems turning these lines into e.g. attributes for class instances - I can read and manipulate the `|`-separated elements without issue.

When I get Python to read and print the second element of that line, I get this.

```
'This is an example.\n\nLook at this paragraph.'
```

The `\n\n` is still there - which on reflection is not really a surprise.

I don't know if my terminology is right but I think I'm basically trying to get Python to treat this as a string literal rather than as a raw string literal. I should add that I know nothing about encoding.

Basically, it would be useful to be able to write e.g. `r'this\nparagraph'` to a file, or even to type `this\nparagraph` directly into one, to see `this\nparagraph` there in it, but then to get Python to print it as

```
this
paragraph
```

having successfully read the file. How might I go about doing this?

**EDIT: Apologies to the first couple of answerers, but I thought I'd rewrite my question to contain fewer red herrings.**

Comment: If the string is `'hello\nworld`', it doesn't actually contain escape characters anymore. It has an actual newline embedded in it. Converting that back to a backslash followed by 'n' is a manual process, `repr` sort of does what you want, but it would also add and possibly escape quotes and tons of other things.

Comment: `repr` wouldn't really fix anything, but it would show what the rawstring version looks like. ie. It would show how the string is constructed and indicate that the backslash is being escaped. In general, if you're having issues with strings, it's a good idea to `print repr(string)` so you can see what the string actually contains.

Answer (score 1):

If `print string` is giving you `'This is an example.\n\nLook at this paragraph.'`, then that means the string probably looks like this:

```
'This is an example.\\n\\nLook at this paragraph.'
```

The `\\` is backslash's own escape character, which makes Python treat it like a normal backslash, instead of reading `\n`, the newline.

The simplest way to fix just the newlines is to use `replace`. Ideally do this when you read the string but I'll show you how it looks with a print:

```
>>> print 'This is an example.\\n\\nLook at this paragraph.'.replace('\\n', '\n')
This is an example.

Look at this paragraph.
```

This replaces the escaped `\\n` with the actual newline character `\n`.

Comment: Sure - I'll run with that, thank you! I guess I thought there might be something a little less clunky-looking...

When you say 'the simplest way' - is there another way?

Comment: @alwphx the better way involves writing data to the file more carefully, but that depends on where the txt file comes from.

Answer (score -1):

Iteration in python works on collections not strings

you can split the file with the following

```
with open('quick.txt', 'r') as f:
    F = f.split("\n")
    for line in F:
        print line
```

or for writing

```
with open('quick.txt', 'w') as f:
    text = "" + (q + "\n" for q in "hello\nworld".split("\n"))
    f.write(text)
```

Personally I like to do all my string prep before I write to a file, and use native python data types for things that are more dynamic rather than writing to the disk.

### EDIT## Iteration works on strings, but not for what you want. ##EDIT

Comment: You misunderstand - at no point am I trying to iterate through the string. I'm iterating through the lines of the file. Q2 is about how to get python to read/print the line in the file as if it were 'hello\nworld' instead of r'hello\nworld'.

Answer (score -1):

You need to open the file in binary mode i.e. wb instead of w. If you don't, the end of line characters are auto-converted to OS specific ones.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open